# Redux timeout thunk error "Actions must be plain objects"

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I'm using redux-thunk and I also want to dispatch some actions with timeout. Because of some reasons (*i want all timeouts in an object, i want to able to cancel them, doesnt really matter now*) I want to have custom 'timeout middleware' and 'action enchancer'

enchancer just emits special type of action:

```
const addTimeoutToAction = (delay, action) => ({
  type: 'TIMEOUT'
  , delay
  , action
})
```

middleware just catches it and should dispatch action after timeout ends

```
({dispatch, getState}) => next => action => {
  if (action && action.type === 'TIMEOUT') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(action.action);
    }, action.delay)
  }
  next(action);
}
```

So my expectation is that dispatch function in the middleware will send action back to the middleware chain, where it will start to go through all again.

My example code works with plain action, however thunked action is not. please help me understand how to reroute delayed action back to middleware chain.

Example code:

http://codepen.io/Fen1kz/pen/zKadmL?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should look like this

```
const action3 = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'action3'
    });
}
```

Whenever you use thunk middleware, you MUST call dispatch to dispatch actions, you cannot return an object.

Here is the corrected codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEKWRK?editors=0010

Hope this helps.

Comment: ha. haha. hahahaha. My mind started to melt when I fixed that small error in example and it worked. haha. I've spend all these 30 minutes just watching how same code fails in my project and succeeds in the example. then I got that i have store creation like `createStore(reducer, Redux.compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), applyMiddleware(timeouts)));` that was the problem. In case you want to check - I've updated codepen, so now it has compose/applyMiddleware and it fails even with your solution.